# What does double bars mean in KL Divergence?

Tags: terminology

I did a google search and only things that pop up are parallel lines or norms, both I don't think makes sense in this context:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence

How do you interpret D(P || Q)?

Comment: $D(P||Q)$ is the KL divergence of $P$ with respect to $Q$. That's it. The expression only makes sense as a whole.

Comment: @user658409 so there's no reason not to write it as e.g. $D(P\color{red}{;} Q)$?

Comment: That is correct.